# Entry Visa to India from United States

Tags: entry-permit

What do I write in  fields asking for previous visa details for entry visa to India? I have never applied for entry visa so don't have those details.

Comment: Try '---' (or 'none' or 'not relevant'). This will show them that you have understood the question, but there is no data that is applicable.

Comment: Sometimes I put [**n/a**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/n-a) (not applicable) on a form's section if there isn't anything to write there, so as not to leave it empty.

Comment: Is it an online questionnaire? (eVISA?) Just leave it empty. Maybe you should review previous questions. But do not worry too much. Indian immigration is chaotic.